# Динамически изменять содержимое корзины

Tags: jquery

Есть корзина на jquery.
В самой корзине при открытии есть возможность добавить доп. акксессуары к заказу.

Сайт на котором корзина - http://ruwolkinzcom.1spa.by/

Скрипт корзины - http://ruwolkinzcom.1spa.by/js/jquery.mycart.js

Сам вызов корзины

```js
<script>
      $(function () {

          var goToCartIcon = function($addTocartBtn){
              var $cartIcon = $(".my-cart-icon");
              var $image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + $addTocartBtn.data("image") + '"/>').css({"position": "fixed", "z-index": "999"});
              $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);
              var position = $cartIcon.position();
              $image.animate({
                  top: position.top,
                  left: position.left
              }, 500 , "linear", function() {
                  $image.remove();
              });
          }

          $('.my-cart-btn').myCart({
              classCartIcon: 'my-cart-icon',
              classCartBadge: 'my-cart-badge',
              affixCartIcon: true,
              checkoutCart: function(products) {
                  $.each(products, function(){
                      console.log(this);
                  });
              },
              clickOnAddToCart: function($addTocart){
                  goToCartIcon($addTocart);
              },
              getDiscountPrice: function(products) {
                  var total = 0;
                  $.each(products, function(){
                      total += this.quantity * this.price;
                  });
                  return total * 0.5;
              }
          });

      });

  </script>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "в корзину", товар добавляется НО только в фоновом режиме, т.е. сразу в корзине не виден, и появляется только если закрыть и открыть корзину заново.

Вопрос следующий - как динамически (вживую) изменять содержимое корзины, чтобы сразу были видны изменения (добавленные товары)?

Comment: по кнопке заказать всё работает

Comment: Смотря как генерируется содержимое модального окна корзины. В целом тебе нужно перезагружать область с товарами и ценой или все окно. Это делается или при помощи AJAX/просто JS на основании данных нужно создавать новый блок с товаром, который положили в заказ и добавлять его ниже

Comment: Я понимаю, что нужно обновлять, но не знаю с чего начать )